# React/Axios - Getting broken image from API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-hooks

I'm trying to display a random image from the dog API URL.

It is currently displaying a broken image. I am using Axios and React and am currently not getting any errors/issues in eslint.

I'm wanting to click the button to display a random image from the API but it's just displaying the `alt` text with a broken image.

**CODE**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {

  const [image, getImage] = React.useState("");

  function btnClick(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    axios
        .get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random")
        .then(response => {
            getImage({ imgs: response.message });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error happened during fetching!", err);
        });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src={image} alt="broken"/>
      <button className = "Button" onClick = {btnClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked and the API response is structured like this:

```
{
  "message": "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/affenpinscher/n02110627_5361.jpg",
  "status": "success"
}
```

When you call `getImage` (which should be called `setImage` in my opinion) like this:

```js
getImage({ imgs : response.data.message });
```

The value of your state variable called `image` changes from a `string` to an `object` with the following structure:

```js
{
    imgs : "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/affenpinscher/n02110627_5361.jpg"
}
```

However, the `img` tag expects a `src` prop of type `string` (a URL) but you're passing it an `object`. You should use `getImage` like this instead:

```js
getImage(response.data.message);
```

Comment: Appreciate it, i've changed everything you suggested and still no difference.

Comment: `getImage(response.data.message)` did it for me, appreciate the help.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that about Axios. I'll update my answer. Please my answer as accepted if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Check the API response](https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random), it doesn't have a `data` field. It has a `message` field with the image URL, and that's the one you should be using.

The eslint warning you're getting has nothing to do with image not displaying. `img` tags should have `alt` property. You only have `src`.

[From mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img):

> The alt attribute holds a text description of the image, which isn't mandatory but is incredibly useful for accessibility

Comment: Ok, I added the alt. Now no errors/issues at all. And, when I change the `data` to `message` and vice versa, there is no difference or error messages.